# Identify 80s or 90s comics with ripped creatures (not dwarves)

Tags: story-identification, comics

It was a comicbook series about fantasy creatures published in the 80s or 90s definitely not online since I was a kid and Internet didn't existed to me. The graphic style was European (*bande dessinée*) or American.

These creatures were bare chested, or wore light clothes, because I remember them being ripped, with abs and pecs, and being mélée-focused but they were **not dwarves**. I mean they were not stocky, but athletic. I don't remember their overall size (I don't remember a scale).

Maybe they were elves but not the tall-and-ranged-attack Tolkien type.

Comment: So, since you state they're not dwarves, they're definitely not short then?

Comment: Was it a manga-style, US style or European-style comic? Was it published in magazines, online, or as a graphic novel?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Is it possible you're thinking of *[Elfquest](https://elfquest.com/)*? The elves in question definitely tend to very toned, and muscular. The degree of focus on *mêlée* varies with them using a mixture of primitive ranged weapons, and a variety of swords, knives, and clubs.

[image: Elfquest image featuring Cutter in the foreground]

Because elves were mentioned, I decided to try *fantasy comic heavily muscled elves* (which surprisingly did not lead me to highly NSFW results). One of the images was of Cutter, which reminded me of reading *Elfquest*  as a child.

Comment: Exactly... how did you find that?, I tried with a lots of different keywords but did find nothing.

Comment: @BebsV: Combination of a lucky search prompt, and having read *Elfquest* as a child.